# Sharepoint List how to add hyperlinks to texts in a column

Tags: asp.net, list, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have a list with two columns. 'Title' and 'Link'

For example if I have an item in list with values:

Title: move
Link: move.aspx

So when an user clicks 'move' on the list I want to redirect to move.aspx page.

Any suggestions how this can be done? I tried using the calculated columns but didnt have much luck on it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Create a Calculated Column:

```
="< a href='" & Link & "'>" & Title & "</a>"
```

Set the outputtype to Number!! This (undocumented) behaviour makes the result be output as HTML, no need to mess around with extra scripts.

Works in SharePoint 2010, 2013, Online (and maybe even in 2007, I never checked)

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column that creates the proper HTML for the link and then add a content editor web part that contains script the shows the html correctly and allows it to be clickable

More info here: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/

Answer (score 0):

**It working fine** with me with a simple trick, put the HTML that you need or JavaScript,

**But don't forget to set the data type in number !!!**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
        <ItemTemplate>    
        <a href='move.aspx?' id="link" >Move</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

Add this code to your grid. This will solve your issue. Happy coding.
```

Comment: `'move.aspx? id="link"` You have an extra space and missing a `'` there.